# VBA 'Vlookup' function operating on dynamic number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure how to combine a Function with a Sub. Most likely, the Sub I have below needs corrections.

I have two tables in two separate sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Both tables have dynamic number of rows but the first rows always start in the same place and the number of columns in both tables is constant, too. Sheet1 data starts in A2 and ends in R2:R and Sheet2 data starts in A3 and ends in H3:H.

I am trying to implement VLOOkUP in column O of Sheet1, that would populate each cell in column O of Sheet1 with relevant values of column D in Sheet2. So far I managed to come up with code as below.

```
Public Function fsVlookup(ByVal pSearch As Range, ByVal pMatrix As Range, ByVal pMatColNum As Integer) As String
    Dim s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(pSearch, pMatrix, pMatColNum, False)
    If IsError(s) Then
        fsVlookup = ""
    Else
        fsVlookup = s
    End If
End Function
Public Sub Delinquency2()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range


    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    pSearch = ws1.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row)
    pMatrix = ws2.Range("$A3:$H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlDown).Row)
    pMatColNum = 4

    Set rng = ws1.Range("O2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each rCell In rng.Cells
             With rCell
                               rCell.FormulaR1C1 = s

            End With
        Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Why code something instead of using formulas on sheet?

Comment: "So far I managed to come up with code as below." And? What does your code do? What exactly do you expect it to do? What is a sample of the data you are looking at? On what conditions does it work as expected? Does it error? etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call the function in your sub using a similar line to below. It then takes your values from your sub and inputs them into the function and returns the value.

You need to dim the ranges in order for them to be recognized correctly in your function. I have updated your code to make it work and you can fiddle around with it to make it work the way you want it to. I also updated a few other spots to figure out the correct ranges, you don't want to use `xlDown` where you were using it, causes an enormous loop covering cells you don't want it to.

```
Public Function fsVlookup(ByVal pSearch As Range, ByVal pMatrix As Range, ByVal pMatColNum As Integer) As String
    Dim s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(pSearch, pMatrix, pMatColNum, False)
    If IsError(s) Then
        fsVlookup = ""
    Else
        fsVlookup = s
    End If
End Function.

Public Sub Delinquency2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range, pMatrix As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    pSearchCol = ws1.Range("D2:D2").Column
    Set pMatrix = ws2.Range("$A3:$H" & ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    pMatColNum = 4

    Set rng = ws1.Range("O2:O" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each rCell In rng.Cells
         With rCell
             rCell.Value = fsVlookup(ws1.Cells(rCell.Row, pSearchCol), pMatrix, pMatColNum)
        End With
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting "Run time error '404' Object required." To explain my intentions to findwindow and Grade 'Eh' Bacon:  I am trying to populate some data in column O of Sheet1 using relevant values from the table in Sheet2. As the size of both tables is different each time I need to do it, I cannot simply enter formulas into each cell as it would be time consuming process so I am trying to avoid it using macro that populates the data automatically regardless the number of rows in each table.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for the run time error you were receiving, it wasn't liking the variables being input into the function, so I dimmed them as what they were looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Make sure to mark my answer for ya :)